# Как получить значение из datepicker?

Tags: javascript

Использую datepicker Tailwind

```
 <input id="datepicker" name="date" datepicker type="text" placeholder="Select date">
```

Хочу что бы при выборе даты, дата сразу же подгружалась в нужное место с `id="open-date-field"`

Написал вот такой код

```
$('#datepicker').click(function() {
    var val = $('#datepicker').val();
    date = val.replace(/\//g, '.');
    console.log(date);
    $('#open-date-field').html(date);
});
```

И вроде бы все хорошо, но, когда я выбираю дату в пикере, дата не подгружается в нужное мне место, но если я опять второй раз нажму на пикер, то дата подгрузится ок и так всегда. Как можно исправить это поведение?

Comment: Скорее всего Вам нужно отслеживать не `click` событие, а `change`.

Comment: Не, change вообще не работает

Comment: `$('#datepicker').on('change', function() {...});`